# Is it possible to add/subtract digits from a data frame column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a column of character variables in a data frame in R (e.g. W41103066, W41103688), and I would like to append '10' to the end of each one so that it can be W4110306610, W4110368810, etc. Similarly, I would like to go from having W4110306610 to W41103066 (remove 10 from the end of each). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try `c(outer(df1$col1, 10:66, FUN = paste0))`

Comment: And to remove, `gsub("10$", "", df$col)` – `10` being the substring to match and `$` being the regex to match at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for adding use `paste()`:

```
df$col <- paste0(df$col, '10')
```

To remove two chars there are various options but one is `tidyr separate` and then drop the extra column:

```
library(tidyr)
df <- separate(df, col = col, into = c('colA', 'colB'), sep = -2) %>%
select(-colB)
```